# Parsing error on line 20 expected curly brace

Tags: reactjs

Line 20:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

18 |       {
  19 |

> 20 |          this.state.employees.map((buddy){
>        |          ^
>     21 |           return({buddy.name})
>     22 |         });
>     23 |       }

So I am getting this parsing error that I have near my map function I do not know why I have this my curly braces are all closed below is my react code

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    employees: [
      {id: 1, name:'Dlo',position:'Accountant'},
      {id: 2, name:'Bron',position:'Police Officer'},
      {id: 3, name:'Hala',position:'Tech Support'},
      {id: 4, name:'Mario',position:'Game Tester'},
    ]
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ul>
      {
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />


         this.state.employees.map((buddy){
          return(<Special id={buddy.id} position= {buddy.position}>{buddy.name}</Special>)
        });
      }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

I am creating a lost to display on my web page

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.employees.map(function(buddy){
          return(<Special id={buddy.id} position= {buddy.position}>{buddy.name}</Special>)
        });`

**You have missed the main part, i.e. "function" keyword.**

Else do this 
`this.state.employees.map(buddy => 
<Special id={buddy.id} position={buddy.position}>{buddy.name}</Special>
);`

"**=>**" -  This is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Please brush up your javascript basics before you hop onto react. Javascript fundamentals are very important.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: this.state.employees.map((buddy) => {
        return (<Special id={buddy.id} position= {buddy.position}>{buddy.name}</Special>)
        });
      } like this but I still get the error

Comment: Remove the semicolon.